# Add entry to right-click menu for a specific filetype

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-desktop

## What I want

I want to add a custom entry to the menu that appears when right-clicking a .jpg/.jpeg for my program (editing images).

## What I tried

I added to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jpegfile\shell a key `test`, in there a second key `command` and set the (default) value of that to notepad.exe (just for testing). Because no `test` entry appeared in the menu, I did the same just unter HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory where it worked!

The file I click is an JPEG and the default value of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.jpg is `jpegfile`.

(Also tested with `txtfile` but with no success.)

What did I do wrong to add a custom command to specific filetypes only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did was correct. Possible reasons why it didn't work include:

1. Windows Update has an annoying tendency in Windows 10 to reset file associations to Windows defaults all the time.
2. You added this facility to the jpegfile key, but the type .jpg may be associated with a different file-type key.

Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.jpg and see what the association is (alternatively, type `ASSOC .jpg` in Command Prompt). If it isn't jpegfile, check what it is, in case you actually want to keep that association.

To give you an example, I have a working right-click menu entry for .png files, which runs the pngout utility on them. I did that by editing the Registry. My current association for .png files is FastStone Image Viewer:

[image: .png file association]

So I changed the shell menu for FastStone's file type key:

[image: Right-click menu entry added]

And now my right-click menu entry works.

Comment: Thanks! This works but is not what I wanted. I want a separate entry, let's call it "Quick edit" and in there some options to choose e.g. "Reduce Quality", "Shrink" and so on.

I tried it now with exefile with success to add this first `test` entry, but still have no clue why it doesn't come up on other filetypes as .jpg or .txt

Comment: I see what you mean. I will change my answer.